# Sort specific xml nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

In the below XML, I need to sort only a specific segment - **attrGroupMany name="allergenRelatedInformation"** based on the **grand child values**. And the rest of the XML should be generated as it is with just this segment sorted.

**FDA**
            **BIG 8**

So all allergenSpecificationAgency that has "**FDA**" and allergenSpecificationName has "**BIG 8**" should come before "**FDA**" and "**TREE_NUTS**". Please suggest how to achieve this in XSLT. Thanks.

```
<ns:MT_TradeItemsExport xmlns:ns="test">
<Header version="2.1">
    <CreationDateTime>2017-02-09T14:19:03.566Z</CreationDateTime>
    <MessageID>0072745000010_9f9cd85e-6d30-4152-a51f-d8491df45486</MessageID>
</Header>
<Payload>
    <ItemRegistration>
        <attr name="numberOfServingsPerPackage">4.0</attr>
    </ItemRegistration>
    <attrGroupMany name="organicClaim">
        <row>
            <attr name="organicTradeItemCode">2</attr>
            <attrMany name="organicClaimAgencyCode">
                <value>6</value>
            </attrMany>
        </row>
    </attrGroupMany>

    <attrGroupMany name="allergenRelatedInformation">
        <row>
            <attr name="allergenSpecificationAgency">FDA</attr>
            <attr name="allergenSpecificationName">BIG 8</attr>
            <attrGroupMany name="allergen">
                <row>
                    <attr name="allergenTypeCode">AC</attr>
                    <attr name="levelOfContainmentCode">FREE_FROM</attr>
                </row>
            </attrGroupMany>
        </row>
        <row>
            <attr name="allergenSpecificationAgency">FDA</attr>
            <attr name="allergenSpecificationName">BIG 8</attr>
            <attrGroupMany name="allergen">
                <row>
                    <attr name="allergenTypeCode">AE</attr>
                    <attr name="levelOfContainmentCode">FREE_FROM</attr>
                </row>
            </attrGroupMany>
        </row>
        <row>
            <attr name="allergenSpecificationAgency">FDA</attr>
            <attr name="allergenSpecificationName">BIG 8</attr>
            <attrGroupMany name="allergen">
                <row>
                    <attr name="allergenTypeCode">AF</attr>
                    <attr name="levelOfContainmentCode">FREE_FROM</attr>
                </row>
            </attrGroupMany>
        </row>
        <row>
            <attr name="allergenSpecificationAgency">FDA</attr>
            <attr name="allergenSpecificationName">BIG 8</attr>
            <attrGroupMany name="allergen">
                <row>
                    <attr name="allergenTypeCode">AM</attr>
                    <attr name="levelOfContainmentCode">FREE_FROM</attr>
                </row>
            </attrGroupMany>
        </row>
        <row>
            <attr name="allergenSpecificationAgency">FDA</attr>
            <attr name="allergenSpecificationName">BIG 8</attr>
            <attrGroupMany name="allergen">
                <row>
                    <attr name="allergenTypeCode">AN</attr>
                    <attr name="levelOfContainmentCode">FREE_FROM</attr>
                </row>
            </attrGroupMany>
        </row>
        <row>
            <attr name="allergenSpecificationAgency">FDA</attr>
            <attr name="allergenSpecificationName">BIG 8</attr>
            <attrGroupMany name="allergen">
                <row>
                    <attr name="allergenTypeCode">AP</attr>
                    <attr name="levelOfContainmentCode">FREE_FROM</attr>
                </row>
            </attrGroupMany>
        </row>
        <row>
            <attr name="allergenSpecificationAgency">FDA</attr>
            <attr name="allergenSpecificationName">BIG 8</attr>
            <attrGroupMany name="allergen">
                <row>
                    <attr name="allergenTypeCode">AY</attr>
                    <attr name="levelOfContainmentCode">FREE_FROM</attr>
                </row>
            </attrGroupMany>
        </row>
        <row>
            <attr name="allergenSpecificationAgency">FDA</attr>
            <attr name="allergenSpecificationName">TREE_NUTS</attr>
            <attrGroupMany name="allergen">
                <row>
                    <attr name="allergenTypeCode">TN</attr>
                    <attr name="levelOfContainmentCode">FREE_FROM</attr>
                </row>
            </attrGroupMany>
        </row>
        <row>
            <attr name="allergenSpecificationAgency">FDA</attr>
            <attr name="allergenSpecificationName">BIG 8</attr>
            <attrGroupMany name="allergen">
                <row>
                    <attr name="allergenTypeCode">UW</attr>
                    <attr name="levelOfContainmentCode">FREE_FROM</attr>
                </row>
            </attrGroupMany>
        </row>
    </attrGroupMany>
</Payload>
```

Comment: Do you want to sort the `row` child elements? What have you tried? Using `xsl:apply-templates/xsl:sort` is kind of straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xsl:perform-sort` or `xsl:apply-templates` together with `xsl:sort`, to sort the `row` children use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="attrGroupMany[@name ='allergenRelatedInformation']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="row">
                <xsl:sort select="attr[@name = 'allergenSpecificationAgency']"/>
                <xsl:sort select="attr[@name = 'allergenSpecificationName']"/>
           </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/ejivdHR

Comment: Thank you, Martin. You saved my life!!